# Ribbon cable question

Tags: ribbon-cable

[image]

Hello, i'm at a complete loss, have never came across that type of a ribbon cable, could anyone point me in the right direction as to the nature of the "bridge" between traces there. Cheers

Comment: It's  a [Flexible PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_electronics) rather than a cable.

Comment: The photo isn't good enough. Is the white thing a component or an earthing pad reinforcement that will be grounded on the equipment chassis by a screw through the flexible PCB?

Comment: I've updated the photo, and no it's not meant to be attached to the ground.

Comment: It looks like it can be shorted or cut to configure something.

Comment: Figured it looks like pads for a smd resistor,but then again the gap between those pads is weirdly small

Comment: Again, it's a special pad to configure the PCB. It can be either shorted with a solder blob or cut apart. Unfortunately don't know the name of this, but it's rather common.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

One **example** why we use something similar:

We have a display which we use to connect to our board. The display comes with a flex foil. We also have a second source for this display from a second vendor. To identify the display vendor type we ask second vendor to short two traces. The flex foil as such is supplied by third party to both LCD vendors without bridging.

The board can easily identify the type of the display connected and load appropriate settings for the display.